# Users disconnecting from Google+ spontaneously

Tags: android, google-plus

I have a problem with Google+ integration
I have integrated Google+ in my app exactly as sample app did.
For some reason, some users that sign in with Google+ get disconnected after a while (might be hours to days), onConnectionFailed called with error code ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, while I know for sure that the user didn't disconnect from Google+ in the app and mPlusClient.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(), mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount() and mPlusClient.disconnect() never called. This error happens to too many people so I find it hard to believe that the problem is that the user signed out in his Google+ account.

This code exist at the base class of all of my activities -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
    .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity")
    .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mPlusClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mPlusClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN    || requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && !mPlusClient.isConnected() && !mPlusClient.isConnecting()) {
                // This time, connect should succeed.
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }

            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
                userCanceledGoogleConnect();
        }
}
```

any kind of help will be very appreciate

Comment: That is odd. There are places users can disconnect on the web or from the Google Settings app. What percentage of users are you seeing disconnected?

Comment: I know about those options, but its unlikely, its happening to too many users

Comment: There are a couple of other cases that will cause sign-in-required: for example if the user had signed out (in app using plusclient.clearDefaultAccount, but without revoking), or by uninstalling and later re-installing the app. Have you see this flow happening - and if so do you know what happens after resolving that error (could be nothing, account chooser, or consent screen, or chooser then consent screen).

Comment: Its defiantly not sign out button or re installation, i have a boolean flag in the shared prefs that raise when the user sign in and turn off when the user sign out, moreover I can see it on my android, that after a couple of days i get signed out automatically. I didn't try to resolve it because I dont want that the account chooser will be raised at that point.

Comment: Ah, one other case if you have multiple accounts is that the user has signed in with more than one. I am wondering if the default account is expiring or similar. If you can reproduce the situation, can you try setting the default account while constructing the plusclient and see if that stops the connectionresult firing the error? Which version of Google Play service are you using?

Comment: I will give it a try and write here how it goes, by the way, I get different wierd behaviour if I set the account name in the constructor - When disconnecting the user without revoking access as shown here "https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#sign_out_the_user", disconnect followed by connect with mPlusClient set on a specific account, even though I cleared default account, The connect succeed and the user stays connected, had to recreate mPlusClient there. I use Google Play service version 4030500.

Comment: Interesting. Could you try with the latest Google Play services as well (4.1 right now, or 4.2 very imminently).

Comment: I can confirm that the 4.1 version fix the sign out bug, regarding the main bug that I reported in this thread I'll be able to answer only after the next version will be uploaded.